# Livewire to update live status message during function execution

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have Livewire Country component which has input text for user to input 2-letter country code. After input the code, user will click on Import button and it calls import function to process. It will find the Country by given code and import the cities. Is there anyway to display a live message to show process status, ex: "Importing for `country name`".

Here is my code:

Livewire component

```
class CityImportComponent extends Component
{
    public string $iso2 = '';
    public string $process_message = '';

    public function resetFilters()
    {
        $this->reset(['iso2', 'process_message']);
    }

    public function getCountryProperty()
    {
        return Country::findByCode($this->iso2)->first();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.import.state-and-city-not-in-france');
    }

    public function import()
    {
        $this->process_message = 'Importing cities for ' . $this->country->name;
    }
}
```

Livewire view

```
<div class="position-relative">
    @if (session()->has('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger mb-3">
            <i class="bi bi-info-circle-fill"></i> {{ session('error') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if (session()->has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success mb-3">
            <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill"></i> {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="position-absolute w-100 h-100" wire:loading wire:target="import">
        <div
            class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start text-white w-100 h-100 bg-secondary ps-3 rounded gap-2">
            <i class="bi bi-arrow-repeat spin"></i> <span wire:model="process_message">{{ $process_message }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form wire:submit.prevent="import">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" name="iso2" wire:model="iso2" placeholder="2-letter country code">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
            Import
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a div and call wire:loading:

```php
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" wire:loading wire:target.longest="import">
    {{ $process_message }}
</div>
```

More info can be found here: [Livewire Loading States](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/loading-states#toggling-elements)

Comment: It doesn't work. It showed previous message once clicking on import button.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<div wire:loading.delay class="float-right">
    <span class="bg-info col-md-12 rounded"><b>Loading...</b>{{ $process_message }}</span>
</div>
```